# How to capture data from HTML page such as auto input

Tags: c#, jquery, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC 5 Webpage with Authentication with C# in the backend. I added a user with a password and my  Chrome browser asked to remember my user and password (Not MVC 5.) The next time, chrome added my user and password automatically.
I tried to access these values using JQuery and by trying to pass it as an object in a HTML.Link. It didnt work.

I checked  the source HTML of the login page, the username and password values were not there. I assume they were filled in after the page was built. However, when I hit the "Submit" button, MVC 5 knows how to access the auto input values and logs me in, using the supplied password and username, whereas if I use a link (eg forget password link, and I want to autofill the username in the ForgotPassword screen from the login screen - I cant.

My question is, is way to programatically get data from the Razor fields after they have been filled in by the browser cookies etc i.e. the same way that the submit button does?

Comment: Surely you can see that allowing access to usernames and passwords programatically would be a very, very bad idea. TL;DR you can't do this

Comment: Sure...when the form is submitted those values exist and you can access any part of form before it does get submitted

Comment: How would one access the values if one uised a link click rather than a submit button?